# Gremlin: How to map vertices together and utilize the edge properties

Tags: gremlin

Using this example graph below, I'm trying to collect a a mapping of terms and weights for each content.

```
v1 = g.addV("content").property("title", "Title 1")
v2 = g.addV("content").property("title", "Title 2")
v3 = g.addV("content").property("title", "Title 3")
v4 = g.addV("content").property("title", "Title 4")
v5 = g.addV("term").property("name", "Term 1")
v6 = g.addV("term").property("name", "Term 2")
g.addE("hasTerm").from(v1).to(v5).property("weight", 5)
g.addE("hasTerm").from(v1).to(v6).property("weight", 8)
g.addE("hasTerm").from(v2).to(v5).property("weight", 10)
g.addE("hasTerm").from(v3).to(v5).property("weight", 15)
g.addE("hasTerm").from(v3).to(v6).property("weight", 6)
g.addE("hasTerm").from(v4).to(v6).property("weight", 8)
```

Example Required Output:

```
[[Title 1, Terms:[[t:Term 1, w:5],[t:Term 2, w:8]]],
 [Title 2, Terms:[[t:Term 1, w:10]]],
 [Title 3, Terms:[[t:Term 1, w:15],[t:Term 2, w:6]]],
 [Title 4, Terms:[[t:Term 2, w:8]]]]
```

I got close to accomplishing this goal, using a query like this:

```java
g.V().has('content', 'title', 'Title 1').as('a').
  out('hasTerm').as('t', 'w').
  select('t', 'w').
    by('name').
    by(inE('hasTerm').values('weight'))
```

And got this result when only looking at terms for 1 content vertex:

```
==>[t:Term1,w:5]
==>[t:Term 2,w:8]
```

But whenever I tried use a query on all vertices with label `content` and group it by content, it doesn't work.

Add additional requirement I still need to solve (after this step) is to find the sum of all the minimum weights between two pieces of content. Comparing `Title 1` and `Title 3` they both share `Term 1` and `Term 2` with varying weights. I would want to take the minimum weight that goes to `Term 1` and add it to the minimum weight going to `Term 2`. Examples of all permutations below:

```
[[Title 1, Title 2, w:5],
[Title 1, Title 3, w:11],
[Title 1, Title 4, w:8],
[Title 2, Title 3, w:10],
[Title 3, Title 4, w: 6]]
```

If this second option would be better to handle simply in code rather than in the graph query, I'll do that, but I'm not sure where how I would do it in the query to begin with.

Comment: I answered the main question below. What sort of output are you looking to generate for the additional question?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use nested `group` steps. Notice I also changed the query from `out` and `inE`, to `outE` and `inV`

```java
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('content').
......1>       group().
......2>         by('title').
......3>         by(outE('hasTerm').
......4>            group().
......5>              by(inV().values('name')).
......6>              by(values('weight'))).unfold()      

==>Title 4={Term 2=8}
==>Title 1={Term 2=8, Term 1=5}
==>Title 3={Term 2=6, Term 1=15}
==>Title 2={Term 1=10}
```